# ssh command not running perl script

Tags: perl, unix, ssh

I have following perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$userinput =  <STDIN>;
chomp ($userinput);
while ( $userinput ne "DONE")
{
        print STDOUT "User typed ----->  $userinput\n";
        $userinput =  <STDIN>;
        chomp ($userinput);
}
```

I have copied this on on unix box, locally this works fine but when I try to run this perl script remotely from another box using ssh, it does not work.

I am running this script using following command.

```
ssh username@hostname /tmp/testremote.pl
```

It just hangs on the STDIN and does not return anything.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Just to be clear: `/tmp/testremote.pl` must exist on the *remote* machine -- does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding [`$|=1;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24|) after the #! line.

Answer (score 2):

your terminal's `STDIN` is probably not being redirected correctly to the remote terminal.

You can try:

```
ssh username@hostname 'echo bla bla bla | /tmp/testremote.pl'
```

And if this works it will indicate that the perl script is fine, but the problem is your redirection.

Comment: Would be a good test if not for the single quote after the last "bla".

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh username@hostname '/tmp/testremote.pl'
```

Please try to add single quote to your command.

Comment: That will only help if the command being sent to ssh requires shell interpolation.